# how to redirect the URL in magento if i click on category or subcategory it should show page

Tags: magento-1.9

how to redirect the URL in Magento if i click on category or subcategory it should show page which i have created because of responsive design i'm doing this

I've created the URL for pages in such a way that the both category and subcategory URL is equal to page URL.

Comment: please elaborate perhaps with some code or screenshots. its unclear what you're asking